# Online questionnaire and biling

Tags: bash, email, scheduled-tasks

**What I am aiming to do**

I am organizing a big event with many invited friends. This big event is subdivided into smaller sub-events and I need to send out a questionnaire to know who wants to come to which sub-event (and where do they want to sleep) and then send an invoice for paying the amount corresponding to the sub-events they registered for.

**My computer skills**

I can code in Bash and in a series of other programming languages (C, C++, R, Python, Julia and Mathematica). I have some knowledge in HTML and CSS but know nothing about Javascript. Globally speaking, I know little about anything that involves the internet!

**How I think about doing it**

I am thinking about using a Google Form to record the answers. Then, I would have a Bash script that would:

1. Download the answers every 3 minutes
2. Check if there are new answers in the past 3 minutes
3. Calculate their bill
4. Send an email with a paypal invoice.

I am currently having issues with this last part (see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/985804/send-a-link-to-pay-via-paypal)), Google Form is not as flexible as I would like it to be and the whole process seems a little cumbersome to me.

**Can you think of a better solution for someone like me who knows nothing about Javascript?**

Comment: For what you need Javascript? You don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [`curl` to fetch Google Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23712343/55075) or skip this step and get them directly into Spreadsheet.
2. Use `watch` command, cron task or while-loop to check new answers each 3 minutes.
3. Calculate their bill in Spreadsheet (where the forms are populated) then fetch data via [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) (either using  `curl`, [PHP](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) or `googlecl`-like command).
4. Use [PayPal Invoicing API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/InvoiceAPIExamples/) to create invoices and send them. Check [this](https://superuser.com/a/985831/87805) for examples.

So no need for Javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I would have thought that a standard method would be to make the whole process occurring on a webpage. This is why I was scared of having to use too much about JavaScript for me. Your solution is quite close to what I suggested as you're sticking with using a Google Form. However, I don't know the watch command and thought about calculating the bill with a R script (R script that would contain the while loope, call bash for mailing and downloading data). The Paypal page you linked will be very helpful as well. Thank you.